# mp3 player works in Chrome and IE8 but not Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I have been trying to embed the Dewplayer mp3 player in a website.  My test site script is below.  This works perfectly in Chrome and IE8 but not Firefox.  I've trawled the net with no luck.  Can anyone see what the problem is, please?
Thanks,
Chris.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>Soundstest</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="rules.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="container">
<div><br>
<br>
<div id="splayers"><br>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
data="C:/Documents and Settings/Taff_2/My Documents/Website/Sounds/dewplayer-playlist.swf"
height="200" width="240"> <param name="wmode" value="transparent"> <param
name="movie"
value="C:/Documents and Settings/Taff_2/My Documents/Website/Sounds/dewplayer-playlist.swf">
<param name="flashvars"
value="xml=C:/Documents and Settings/Taff_2/My Documents/Website/Sounds/Playlist.xml"></object></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried opening the .swf file directly in Firefox and it opens and runs fine - it even picks up the playlist.  So it appears to be a function of how it is inserted into the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Is that webpage out at an http:// URL?  The "data" attribute of `<object>` is supposed to be a URL, not a filename... perhaps that's biting you?

Comment: No, I'm building the site on my PC at present so it's the file address on my C drive. Is it possible that it would upset Firefox, and not upset Chrome or IE, because it doesn't start with http?  If you think it possible I'll ignore it until I get it loaded.